# Send a email when a email from a particular template is sent

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I want to sent a email every time a email from a particular template is send in Dynamics CRM 2011. I tried to use a workflow : 
When a mail is created, i tried to add a condition to check the template of the mail which has been sent, but I can't find the condition on the template in the differents conditions available

Any Suggestions to create such a workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try base your filter on a keyword in the subject of the mail. Can you try this ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to do this on the template, because if I work on the subject of the mail, the workflow will not work if the template is modified,